# Reading .wav files - Not reading header?

Tags: c++, file, text, wav

I am trying to read the header information from a .wav file, and I'm reading the following properties of the file:

```
    type 
    size
    Format Tag
    Format Length
    Channels
    Sample Rate
    Average Bytes Second
    Block Align
    Bits Per Sample
    Data size
```

Now, everything reads perfectly up until reading in Sample Rate, then, the output is either "0" value or just NULL.

Here is the code: (I have opened the text file, and passed the pointer to the member function)

```
bool Wav::readHeader(FILE *dataIn)
{
   char type2[4];
   fread(this->type, sizeof(char), 4, dataIn);

   fread(&this->size, sizeof(int), 1, dataIn);

   fread(this->type, sizeof(char), 4, dataIn);

   fread(this->type, sizeof(char), 4, dataIn);

   fread(&this->format_length, sizeof(short), 1, dataIn);

   fread(&this->format_tag, sizeof(short), 1, dataIn);

   fread(&this->channels, sizeof(short), 1, dataIn);


   fread(&this->sample_rate, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, dataIn);

   fread(&this->avg_bytes_sec, sizeof(unsigned short), 1, dataIn);

   fread(&this->block_align, sizeof(short), 1, dataIn);

   fread(&this->bits_per_sample, sizeof(short), 1, dataIn);

   return true;
}
```

And the class members are defined as:

```
    char type[4]; 
    int size;
    unsigned short format_tag;
    unsigned short format_length;
    unsigned short channels;
    unsigned int sample_rate;
    unsigned short avg_bytes_sec;
    unsigned short block_align;
    unsigned short bits_per_sample;
    unsigned int data_size;
```

Does anyone have any solutions or suggestions?

(P.S. Apologies if this question is not right. I have tried to write it the best I could!)

Comment: Is it a Windows question? If so, why not use proper API to separate headers from payload?

Comment: No, not windows. Compiling through g++ and can't use API's

Comment: `avg_bytes_sec` is 32-bit value and not `unsigned short` you have, see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Your header fields look slightly off. Unless I missed something, you appear to be trying to read the samplerate from offset 22. The samplerate is located at offset 24, see https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/   .  You might also want to use types with guaranteed sizes (int32_t and friends).

Comment: Aha thank you. Roman. So, when it says "WORD" on the url provided, do I assume this means char?

Comment: @user1582478: `WORD` is microsoftese for `int16_t`; `DWORD` means `int32_t`.

Comment: @Michael - Can I read the first 44 characters in the .wav file, and then handle the offsets there?

Comment: Assuming it's a PCM WAVE file, yeah.

Comment: Also, is there a particular reason you're using C FILEs and not C++ file streams?

Comment: @MikeSeymour, almost correct - WORD and DWORD are unsigned.

Comment: Right, this is really, really, confusing me.. Couldn't I just read the first 44 values into a vector<unsigned> and then process the offsetX/Y accordingly? Would this work...?

Comment: If you read them into a `vector<char>`, yes, it would work. The `unsigned` data type is likely a 32 bit integer on your platform, and not a single byte.

Comment: @user1582478: Don't forget to mark your question as answered if it's been answered, seeing as this is a Q&A site.

Comment: Aha, how do I do it? Sorry. I give you rep, just, don't know how to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2):

If you had tightly packed structs representing the (PCM) WAVE's header, it would look like this:

```
struct Riff
{
  char chunkId[4]; // "RIFF" (assuming char is 8 bits)
  int chunkSize; // (assuming int is 32 bits)
  char format[4]; // "WAVE"
};

struct Format
{
  char chunkId[4]; // "fmt "
  int chunkSize;
  short format; // assuming short is 16 bits
  short numChannels;
  int sampleRate;
  int byteRate;
  short align;
  short bitsPerSample;
};

struct Data
{
  char chunkId[4]; // "data"
  int chunkSize; // length of data
  char* data;
};

struct Wave // Actual structure of a PCM WAVE file
{
  Riff riffHeader;
  Format formatHeader;
  Data dataHeader;
};
```

Essentially, your problem is that `format_length` (`Format::chunkSize` in my struct) and `avg_bytes_sec` (`Format::byteRate` in my struct) are 2 bytes each in your code, but they should each be 4. You're also not reading the data subchunk's header, but I assume that's intentional?

To read, you can do something like this:

```
void readWave(std::ifstream& file, Wave& wave)
{
  // First read the RIFF header
  file.read(wave.riffHeader.chunkId,                                   4);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.riffHeader.chunkSize),       4);
  file.read(wave.riffHeader.format,                                    4);

  // Now read the FORMAT header
  file.read(wave.formatHeader.chunkId,                                 4);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.chunkSize),     4);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.format),        2);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.numChannels),   2);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.sampleRate),    4);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.byteRate),      4);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.align),         2);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.bitsPerSample), 2);

  // Now read the DATA header
  file.read(wave.dataHeader.chunkId,                                   4);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.dataHeader.chunkSize),       4);

  // The actual data goes in wave.dataHeader.data, so you can allocate it
  // and then read direclty into it now
}
```

[Michael's link is the one I always use when I need to read/write a WAVE file](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) (which I've had to do several times). I suggest you read it carefully.

If you've got extra chunks in your WAVE file before your "data" chunk, this code should be able to skip them:

```
void readWave(std::ifstream& file, Wave& wave)
{
  // First read the RIFF header
  file.read(wave.riffHeader.chunkId,                                   4);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.riffHeader.chunkSize),       4);
  file.read(wave.riffHeader.format,                                    4);

  // Now read the FORMAT header
  file.read(wave.formatHeader.chunkId,                                 4);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.chunkSize),     4);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.format),        2);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.numChannels),   2);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.sampleRate),    4);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.byteRate),      4);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.align),         2);
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.formatHeader.bitsPerSample), 2);

  // WAVE files are just a special type of RIFF file, so it's possible
  // there are other chunks, like "fact" chunks. We'll skip over these
  // extra chunks until we find a "data" chunk
  char chunkId[4] = {0};
  int chunkSize = 0;
  while (file.read(chunkId, 4) &&
         (chunkId[0] != 'd' ||
          chunkId[1] != 'a' ||
          chunkId[2] != 't' ||
          chunkId[3] != 'a'))
    {
      file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&chunkSize), 4); // Read the chunk's size
      file.seekg(chunkSize, std::ios_base::cur); // Skip the chunk
    }

  // We've found the DATA chunk and header
  wave.dataHeader.chunkId[0] = chunkId[0];
  wave.dataHeader.chunkId[1] = chunkId[1];
  wave.dataHeader.chunkId[2] = chunkId[2];
  wave.dataHeader.chunkId[3] = chunkId[3];
  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wave.dataHeader.chunkSize),       4);

  // The actual data goes in wave.dataHeader.data, so you can allocate it
  // and then read direclty into it now
}
```

Comment: Hello, so can I use this type of structure inside a class? Or, could I possibly have different methods "riff", "Format", "Data" that passes an ifstream to get data? -- Confused

Comment: Sure you could. I'm not sure I entirely understand what it is you're asking though...

Comment: I just added a method about reading. Hopefully it answers your question.

Comment: Hello, thank you :D it worked.. I think!! Quick question.. If I had data = new char[SIZE_OF_DATA] then can I just read it in.. E.g. file.read(this->data,   this->dataSize); ??

Comment: For example.. What should the data type be for the actual data? When I have it as char, I seem to just get "? #" or something.. Also, with a 41KB file, and, after the header.. Should the data size by 4?

Comment: @user1582478: Yes, you can do `file.read(data, dataSize)` assuming `data` has been allocated to `dataSize` bytes and `dataSize` is the same as `wave.dataHeader.chunkSize`. For your second question, it depends on `bitsPerSample`. If `bitsPerSample` is 16, which it probably is, cast the `data` pointer from a `char*` to a `short*` (and divide `dataSize` by two for the size of this new, casted array). Don't try to read `data` as a string... it's raw binary data, not text.

Comment: Hey, I'll try and do the file.read(data, dataSize).. Just to mention.. The Bits per Sample is 8... I get the following data:      Chunk ID: RIFF
Chunk Size: 44154
Format: WAVEfmt 
Format ID: fmt 
Number of Channels: 1
Sample Rate: 22050
Byte Rate: 22050
Align: 1
Bits Per Sample: 8
Data ID: fact
Data Size: 4 -> look ok?

Comment: @user1582478: Oh gosh... that complicates things. First of all, you didn't say what `wave.formatHeader.format` was, but I'm guessing it's not 1. If it's not 1, then your WAVE file has non-PCM data (i.e. it's compressed audio) or it's "extensible", and this can be seen by the presence of your "fact" chunk (notice the data should be in a "data" chunk, not a "fact" chunk). In that case, [carefully read this page on Wave File Specifications](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/audioformats/wave/wave.html). The code I posted is for simple WAVE files, but hopefully it'll help you get started.

Comment: Hello, yes - the wave.formatHeader.format = 1. I know about the "fact" chunk.. Does this mean that I have a long way to go lol? I'll have a look through the wave specifications again.. This is complicated!!

Comment: @user1582478: Oh really? Well if the `wave.formatHeader.format = 1` then you do have PCM audio and things aren't too complicated, and you just have an extra "fact" chunk. You can read over and skip this "fact" chunk (if you read a chunk and it's ID is "fact" just read it's size (which you say is 4), and skip the next bytes (so in your case, read the "fact" chunk, read it's size (4), and skip the next 4 bytes)). You can just ignore the "fact" chunk. But don't get it mixed up with the "data" chunk, which is where the real data is stored!

Comment: Sorry about this.. So if I create a new temp variable, that stores the skipped bytes (4) and then read the data from there? But, what would by my dataSize then? Still be 4? .. If you get some free time, would you mind quickly doing an example? I know it's a lot to ask, just this is killing my brain haha!

Comment: Heyy thanks :) But dataHeader.chunkSize is still = 4.. Is this correct?

Comment: @user1582478: woops, forgot to re-read the chunk size. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks aha :)! Okay, reading the block data in as a char doesn't work, just produces "H?" .. What if I read it in as as a "int", or "short" and then re cased it? Sorry to keep asking

Comment: @user1582478: It does work. It's not text. It's raw bytes of data. `char`s are numbers too.

Comment: Aha, no, there are no numbers.. If I use chars, I get this as output.. http://pastebin.com/ZQynQ2ar that cannot be correct, right? lol

Comment: @user1582478: stop looking at it as text. A `char` **is a number**. What you're looking at is the ASCII interpretation of these numbers.

Comment: But there is no numbers, just "?", "~", "{,}" I don't see the ASCII interpretation of these? Sorry I might be missing something

Comment: @user1582478: *sigh* if you don't understand what you're looking at, you're getting too far ahead of yourself. If you don't know that `char` **is a number**, you need to slow way down. If you're printing these things out to the console, cast them to an integer first. Otherwise, you will see the ASCII interpretation of these numbers... Beyond that, I've helped all I can.

Comment: I'm an absolute idiot!! haha :) Thank you so much for your help! I'm now getting positive and negative numbers.. Now to write an FFT, wish me luck ;)!

Comment: @user1582478: Good luck :) I hope you read the links people gave, because 8-bit PCM data in WAV files are stored as `unsigned char`s. I read the raw bytes as `char`s. You can simply cast them to the correct type, which it sounds like would be `unsigned char` in your 8-bit case.